# Optimize a stored procedure using subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'im working on optimization of stored procedure that uses a subquery.
I need to replace this subquery to get less execution time.

code:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       detail= case when ( DC_ID in ( select DC_ID 
                                      from TableFinale1 
                                      where frais is not null 
                                      and WDT is not null 
                                      and type <> 'CDFS'
                                      )
                         )
                    then 'OK'
                    Else '' 
                    End       
into TableFinale2
From TableFinale1 t1
```

Comment: Are you using MySql *or* SQL Server? They are different products.

Comment: mysql   doesn't support table in INTO

Comment: What exacty are you asking here? There's nothing "wrong" with your query as it is. You could use *exists* but this would likely yield the same plan. If you need help tuning the query, include the table schema definitions, indexes and  [Paste the actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Comment: Possibly a windowed conditional `count` would work here. But without seeing tables, indexes and query plans, cannot say

Comment: You need to inspect (and if wanting help provide) your execution plan to find out where the performance issue lies and how to attempt to solve it. Google Paste The Plan.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to a JOIN, BUT... this will cause duplicate `T1` records if there are more than 1 `DC_ID` that have a non-null `frais`, a non-null `WDT`, and a `type<>'CDFS`. So it's not exactly 1:1 unless your data fits the mold.

```
SELECT t1.*, CASE WHEN t2.DC_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'OK' END
FROM TableFinale1 t1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN TableFinale1 t2
       ON t1.DC_ID = t2.DC_ID
       AND t2.frais is not null 
       and t2.WDT is not null 
       and t2.type <> 'CDFS'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to predict performance changes without a query plan. If there are no indexes on TableFinale1.DC_ID,
maybe a prepared filtered and indexed temporary table will help. Assuming DC_ID `bigint`:

```
create table #temp(DC_ID bigint not null primary key)

insert #temp 
    select distinct DC_ID 
    from TableFinale1 
    where 
        frais is not null 
        and WDT is not null 
        and type <> 'CDFS'
        
select t1.*, case when #temp.DC_ID is not null then 'OK' else '' end as [detail]
into TableFinale2
From 
    TableFinale1 t1
    left join #temp on #temp.DC_ID=t1.DC_ID
```